# Html.EnumDropdownListFor can I order alphabetically?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

I love the new Html.EnumDropdownListFor in MVC 5.1, and I see that I can specify the order of values within the Display attribute like this:

```
    public enum AssignableDataFieldEnum
    {
        [Display(Name = "Code Value", Order=1)]
        CodeValue = 1,
        [Display(Name = "Final Digit", Order=2)]
        FinalDigit = 2,
        [Display(Name = "Group Number", Order=3)]
        GroupNumber = 3,
        [Display(Name = "Sequence Number", Order=4)]
        SequenceNumber = 4
}
```

This solution seems short sighted with localization.  Is there a way to automatically have MVC order the DDL alphabetically for me?

Comment: `Order` doesn't seem to sort it for me.

Comment: Create an extension method that transforms an Enum into a SelectList. Also I would recommend not using Enums and instead use classes even if they're KeyValuePair or Tuple.

Comment: Starting at 1, have you no god?

Answer (score 9):

I came up with a solution that gets the Enum values, sorts them, and then makes a call to `HtmlHelper.DropDownListFor()`.

```
public static MvcHtmlString EnumSortedDropDownListFor<TModel, TEnum>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TEnum>> expression, string optionLabel = null, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes = null) {
    ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
    var selectList = EnumHelper.GetSelectList(metadata.ModelType).OrderBy(i => i.Text).ToList();
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(optionLabel) && selectList.Count != 0 && String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectList[0].Text)) {
        selectList[0].Text = optionLabel;
        optionLabel = null;
    }

    return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, selectList, optionLabel, htmlAttributes);
}
```

Comment: A asp.net core version of this would be handy... :-)

Comment: this code really works. @jhilden you can slect as "Answer". you can change 
"IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes" to "object htmlAttributes"

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to automatically have MVC order the DDL alphabetically for me?

I don't see how. None of the overloads appear to take any form of sorting parameters such as ASC or DESC. It seems like you'd either have to implement your own version of EnumDropDownListFor, potentially using EnumDropDownListFor itself, or use a javascript solution to sort the select element after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

You could benefit from the `System.Web.Mvc.Html.EnumHelper.GetSelectList` method and use `DropDownListFor` instead of `EnumDropdownListFor`, something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Type, EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(MailTemplateType), Model.Type).OrderBy(t => t.Text))
```

Comment: A little shorter syntax for .Net Core 6
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Type, Html.GetEnumSelectList<EnumType>().OrderBy(t => t.Text))

Answer (score 0):

If you have negative numbers or more then 1 digit in your enum, add `OrderBy(e => int.Parse(e.Value))` to your HtmlHelper.GetEnumSelectList Method:

```
asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<WineSugarContent>().OrderBy(e => int.Parse(e.Value))"
```

Answer (score -2):

There is.

Just set your enum items in order you want them displayed. Like this:

```
'// VB.NET
Public Enum AceFriendlyFlags

    <Display(Name:="This folder only")>                      '// Will be at pos 1
    ThisFolderOnly = AceFlags.None

    <Display(Name:="This folder, subfolders and files")>     '// Will be at pos 2
    ThisFolderSubfoldersAndFiles = AceFlags.CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE + AceFlags.OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE

    <Display(Name:="This folder and subfolders")>            '// Will be at pos 3
    ThisFolderAndSubfolders = AceFlags.CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE

    etc...
```

Comment: What happens if you need to insert a value that fits in between 2 and 3? If these are persisted, you just introduced a serious bug.

Comment: If you are persisting your enum values, then you should probably be explicitly  numbering them anyway. However, if you insert an entry with value 100 between values 2 and 3, I don't know if it will sort the way you want. I don't know if it sorts by value, or literally by order of definition.

Comment: This is only a solution before real that using those enums is stored in the DB, when in production if you already have data in DB and change the order of your enum, it will make your data to be wrong because it was already stored with the previous values.